# Is there a tool to get statistics about data in a Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra

I trying to find a way how to get some statistics info about data in a table (columns population, how many partitions,..).
For example in mariaDB there is possibility to execute `ANALYZE TABLE` it will generate table with info about data.
Do we have internal or external tools to do it in cassandra?
It's good to know this before creating `cassandra-stress` profile.

if it's known question please point me, but honestly I didn't find clear answer in internet.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the command `nodetool tablestats`.

It will display metadata about tables in your database including:

- number of SSTables
- data size on disk
- number of partitions (keys)
- min/max/mean partition sizes

The command format is:

```
$ nodetool tablestats keyspace_name.table_name
```

For details, see [the `tablestats` page at the Apache Cassandra website](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/nodetool/tablestats.html). Cheers!

Comment: sure, but how to get info about population in `text` column or about distribution in `int` column. we have powerful `cassandra-stress` tool, but how to get info about existed table.

Comment: There is no such tool. If you think about it, Cassandra is designed billions and billions of records that is distributed across hundreds of nodes. To get that level of metadata detail would require massive amounts of processing. Cheers!